# Iterating over same-name objects of different classes

Tags: perl, loops, methods

I have multiple Perl objects, all of different classes, say triangle, square and circle. All classes/objects/instances have an equally named method, say `render`.

How do I loop over them, invoking the same methods in all of them?

Comment: Seems like what you want are abstract_classes http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=253720

Comment: Yes, you might be right. But the article you mentioned is 12 years old. May be the issues the author mentioned are (partly) ansered by the 'signature ' feature of Perl 5.20?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I am not familiar with perl.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see a problem:

```
for my $obj ($triangle, $square, $circle) {
    $obj->render;
}
```

Or, more shortly

```
$_->render for $triangle, $square, $circle;
```